# making certain function calls involving pandas columns more comprehensive

Tags: python, pandas

In my codebase I have a function that accepts a pandas dataframe and needs to add hundreds of columns by computing some data from the available dataframe.

The data is computed by calling custom functions accepting some pandas series and custom parameters. Schematically the code looks something like this

```
def compute_columns(df):

      df['C1'] = foo1(df['A_1'], df['B_1'], ..., df['Z_1'], p_1,..., p_n)
      ... 
      df['C_n'] = fooN(df['A_n'], df['B_n'], ..., df['Z_n'], q_1,..., q_n)
```

Every function *foo* accepts different types of columns from *df* and a different set of parameters. The parameters are fixed integers/strings.

Given that there are many such lines, the code looks pretty clumsy. So my first question is

> What are some suggestions to make such idiom more compact?

In addition to this, I'd like to be able to compute the new columns by encoding (for each new column) the function used for computing it and the required parameters. I was thinking that something along these lines might work:

```
  columns = {'C1': (foo1, ('A_1', ..., 'Z_1'), (p_1,...p_n)), ..., 
             'C_n': (fooN, ( A_n, ..., Z_n), (q_1,..., q_n))}

  def compute_columns(df):

      for c in columns:
          func, pdcols, params = columns[c]
          df[c] = func(*([df[e] for e in pdcols] + params))
```

With regards to this I wonder

> Is there an even better way to achive the desired result?

I am looking for whatever would be the most pythonic way and would achieve the greatest amount of clarity and comprehension. Somehow I feel that what I am doing here is clumsy/old and that there must be something available for such purposes.